# Where is the Traffic Sources report in Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Where is the `Traffic Sources Report` in Universal Analytics?

I'm in [Unit 2.2 of "Getting Started with Digital Analytics"](https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course01/unit?unit=2&lesson=2) and in the existing Universal Analytics account I can only find `Realtime Traffic Sources`, and there is nobody on my site at the moment.

When I search for `Traffic Sources Report` in Analytics, the only thing that comes up is the `Real Time traffic sources`.﻿  Did they change this from the days of Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Traffic Sources" has been renamed "Acquisition"

[image: Acquisition]